# Convert UCT to British Summer Time Athena

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I'm working with a data set in Athena where all the timestamps are UTC, but I need to adjust to British Summer Time, i.e. add an hour for all timestamps between 1:00am on the last Sunday in March and 1:00am on the last Sunday in October. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

List of supported time zones does not contain `BST` but has `Europe/London` which AFAIK should match it. To convert time zone use [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#time-zone-conversion):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (time) AS (
    VALUES (timestamp '2022-02-01 10:00:00'),
    (now())
) 

-- query
select time, time AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'
from dataset
```

Output:

| time | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 10:00:00.000 UTC | 2022-02-01 10:00:00.000 Europe/London |
| 2022-04-13 12:13:06.610 UTC | 2022-04-13 13:13:06.610 Europe/London |